# Meteor Iron:Router how to prevent URL from changing before onBeforeAction

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a redirect clause in an `onBeforeAction`, but if I put a breakpoint at the beginning, the URL has already changed to the desired path. Is there a way to prevent the url from changing until `onBeforeAction` has finished?

Comment: No, but you can redirect inside it using Router.go('/');

Comment: That is what I'm doing, but I don't want the URL to change unless the redirect if statement fails. Specifically I have an onBeforeAction that authenticates a user and redirects if auth fails. But the URL has already changed before the onBeforeAction has had a chance to authenticate. I thought that was part of the point of onBeforeAction. In practice this works fine, but my mocha tests are failing because the user should not be able to see the target URL if they didn't authenticate properly.

Comment: If you change route by click you can create event click body for everything and save url to some session

Comment: `Router.onRun` is what you are looking for.